# How to render multiple AR models in the same activity using AR Core?

Tags: android, arcore

So I am currently working with an application that is rendering the models using AR Core Sceneform SDK -
I am using the amazing library maintained by [Thomas Gorisse](https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/sceneform-android-sdk) to render models in the same scene.

```
    public void loadModels(String url) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        WeakReference<MainActivity> weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(this);
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, Uri.parse(url))
                .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
                .setAsyncLoadEnabled(true)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(model -> {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Model Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    MainActivity activity = weakActivity.get();
                    if (activity != null) {
                        activity.model = model;
                    }
                })
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load model", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null;
                });

    }
```

I use this to grab a url of the model and load it in the scene, as far as I know AR Core can only load a model as a new intent using Scene Viewer.

```
Intent sceneViewerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sceneViewerIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://arvr.google.com/scene-viewer/1.0?file=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Avocado/glTF/Avocado.gltf"));
sceneViewerIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
startActivity(sceneViewerIntent);
```

We have been asked to switch to ARCore completely so is there a way to achieve the same process in AR Core also, to load models in the same activity without launching a new intent everytime.

Answer (score -1):

This is the Sceneform library with many tutorials. Have a look at those before asking trivial questions like these.